# Installing apcu via pecl fails on Debian

Tags: php, debian, pear, pecl

On Debian, I have installed `php5`, `php5-dev`, `php-pear`.

Then I try to install apcu, but I get this error. Any idea?

```
# pecl install apcu
Failed to download pecl/apcu within preferred state "stable", latest release is version 4.0.7, stability "beta", use "channel://pecl.php.net/apcu-4.0.7" to install
install failed

# pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/apcu-4.0.7
downloading apcu-4.0.7.tgz ...
Starting to download apcu-4.0.7.tgz (118,670 bytes)
..........................done: 118,670 bytes
43 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
Enable full APC compatibility [yes] : yes
Enable internal debugging in APCu [no] : 
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root2kAfTA/apcu-4.0.7
running: /tmp/pear/temp/apcu/configure --enable-apc-bc=yes --enable-apcu-debug=no
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20100525
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking whether to enable APCu support... yes, shared
checking if APCu should provide APC full compatibility support... yes
checking if APCu should be allowed to use rwlocks... yes
checking if APCu should be built in debug mode... no
checking if APCu should clear on SIGUSR1... no
checking if APCu will use mmap or shm... mmap
checking if APCu should utilize spinlocks before flocks... no
configure: WARNING: APCu has access to native rwlocks
checking for sigaction... yes
checking for union semun... no
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking valgrind/memcheck.h usability... no
checking valgrind/memcheck.h presence... no
checking for valgrind/memcheck.h... no
checking for shm_open in -lrt... yes
checking whether to include code coverage symbols... no
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gawk... (cached) nawk
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
running: make
sh: 1: make: not found
ERROR: `make' failed
```

**EDIT:** ops, I didn't have "make" installed (which is ridiculous, if pecl needs it it should be a dependency and have been installed automatically while installing the above packages)

Anyway, now I get this error:

```
In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/apcu/apc.c:44:0:
/usr/include/php5/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: fatal error: pcre.h: No such file 
or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [apc.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Looks like another dependency is missing.

Shouldn't these package manager be able to install all their dependencies automatically?

Is there an easier way out of this than manually installing every single piece that turns out to be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way on Debian would be to use `apt-get install php5-apcu`
You might need to add special package repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, in order to pick this package up:

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php55 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php55 all
```

---

> I didn't have "make" installed (which is ridiculous, if pecl needs it
>   it should be a dependency and have been installed automatically while
>   installing the above packages)

I second that. It should be a dependency and you should get a proper message during phpize. But i'm unsure, if development tools for building or compiling should be installed automatically.

---

Possible alternative: use a tool called Pickle.

Download: http://www.pierrejoye.com/pickle/pickle.phar

`php pickle.phar install apcu`

Comment: On another server, I followed your first method, it apparently installed the package but the extension is still not available in PHP. I tried adding 'extension="apcu.so"' to php.ini, changed nothing. Then I copied the apcu.so file from where it was installed to where all other php extensions really are, and still no luck. Any idea?

Comment: Two things come to my mind: a) Please check, that you added the APCu extension to the correct php.ini file. On debian there might be several configs, e.g. one for CLI and one for webserver and possibly more, if you have a FCGI setup (one per vhost/server block). `php -i | grep php.ini, php -m | grep apcu` b) Please check, that the version of the APCu extensions fits your PHP version. If the extension was compiled for another version of PHP and is not fitting, PHP will print an error message. But that's quite off, because apt-get fetched it and machted it to your version.

Comment: It turns out that the version installed via apt (which was the one I copied to the extensions folder and used) was broken. I could figure that out  by running ```php -m```, and noticing an error message at the beginning, like "could not initialize module". So I uninstalled that one and used the one that was installed via PECL, and that one works.

Comment: Ah, ok. And i excluded this in my last sentence :( This can happen, if the sources for apt are mixed. PHP is fetched from one source (or is preinstalled on the server) and the packages are fetched from http://packages.dotdeb.org.      Anyway: Glad you solved it.